# Junos feature to accept multiple BGP paths from multiple peer AS

Tags: cisco, bgp, juniper, cisco-ios, juniper-junos

Cisco IOS provides this hidden BGP command:

```
router bgp <ASN>
  bgp bestpath as-path multipath-relax
```

It allows the router to install multiple BGP prefixes with distinct as-path'es (but requiring same as-path length).

Source: http://blog.alwaysthenetwork.com/tutorials/bgp-multipath-relax/

Does JunOS provide a similar feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [it is possible](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos11.4/topics/reference/configuration-statement/multipath-edit-protocols-bgp.html). Use the `multiple-as` option for the `multipath` setting like this:

```
set protocols bgp group MY-PEERS multipath multiple-as
```